# Flutter unit test question. How to test local variable is changed?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, testing

```
/// A flag that indicates whether the NotificationProvider is being processed.
  bool _isProcess = false;

  set isProcess(bool value) {
    _isProcess = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool get isProcess => _isProcess;

  NotificationProvider({required this.fetchNotificationUseCase});

  //TODO("Satoshi"): catch exception or error
  /// Fetch notification from api-server.
  Future<void> fetchNotification() async {
    try {
      isProcess = true;
      final res = await fetchNotificationUseCase.fetchNotification();

      notificationList.clear();
      notificationList.addAll(res);

      isProcess = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      isProcess = false;
      notifyListeners();
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

I want to test isProcess property is changed to true and false. But the only I can test is just isProcess is false after fetchNotification method is completed.
How to test isProcess's change ?

This is a test code what I wrote

```
  test('then isProcess is being false', () async {
    await notificationProvider.fetchNotification();

    expect(notificationProvider.isProcess, false);
  });
```

Comment: `notificationProvider.isProcess` is not a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch value changing using `addListener` method in `ChangeNotifier`.

sample code

```dart
test('isProcess changes true then false', () async {
  expect(notificationProvider.isProcess, false);
  int listenerCounts = 0;
  List<bool> matches = [true, false];
  final listener = () {
    expect(notificationProvider.isProcess, matches[listenerCounts]);
    listenerCounts++;
  }
  notificationProvider.addListener(listener);
  await notificationProvider.fetchNotification();
  notificationProvider.removeListener(listener);
});
```

Comment: It is little bit tricky but looks fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`fetchNotification` synchronously sets `isProcess = true` before doing asynchronous work.  You therefore can synchronously check that `notificationProvider.isProcess` transitions from `false` to `true`, and later check that it returns to `false` after all asynchronous work has completed:

```dart
  test('then isProcess is being false', () async {
    expect(notificationProvider.isProcess, false);
    var future = notificationProvider.fetchNotification();
    expect(notificationProvider.isProcess, true);
    await future;
    expect(notificationProvider.isProcess, false);
  });
```